# Selenium Webdriver The system cannot find the file specified in visual studio 2017 error

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2017

I have the selenium webdriver libraries added to my WordpressAutomation project. However, when I run the unit tests, I get the below error. The WordpressTests references the WordpressAutomation project. I am not sure what to do here:

```
 Message: Test method WordpressTests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=3.141.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

[image: Visual Studio showing dependencies and selenium libraries]

Comment: You need to add the `Selenium.WebDriver` package to your tests too, it's a bit weird but that fixed similar issues for me

Answer (score 0):

For some reason **Firefox Webdriver** is not working and giving out error messages. I have added the **Selenium.Webdriver** packages to both the projects and then added the Chrome Webdriver packages. Once I switched from **Firefox Webdriver** to **Chrome Webdriver**, everything worked.

Comment: This answer should be an edit to the question. Please use the [edit link](/posts/54945042/edit) on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @DebanjanB Please read the answer in its entirety before commenting. This is not additional information, this is the asker posting their solution to the problem.